# How to reset all items in a groupbox, but not any items outside said groupbox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, reset, groupbox

I'm working a WPF application which has a number of groupboxes, each containing 3-4 controls a piece. Each of these groupboxes contains a reset button.

Instead of explicitly writing a line for each item the groupbox reset buton should reset is there a way to have the reset button only reset all items for the groupbox it's contained upon?

When researching this issue I found the following post which seems relevant but I'm unsure how to extend Nathan's answer to do this: [What is the best way to clear all controls on a form C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297526/what-is-the-best-way-to-clear-all-controls-on-a-form-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls) as an source of methods you need.

First of all you need to find groupbox that contains button. To do that use `sender` argument form click event it is reference to button that was clicked and call `FindVisualParent` method from one of answers in that question. This will give you groupbox.

Then Find all ui elements by `FindVisualChildren<DependencyObject>` method. This will give you super set of controls that are to be cleared.

Then it is just a loop over this as in question that you referenced. Note that that question was intended for winforms not wpf so you will have to revise the `controldefaults` dictionary which handles grouping controls ~(`Panel` `GroupBox`) which is not needed here (and would not work in wpf).

Answer (score 1):

You might add a TAG to each control telling which property is beeing edited in the control, and then on reset press, you travel up the button to find containing GroupBox, then down to find all controls contained in this GroupBox, and then you find, with the TAGs, the name of the properties that needs reset. You then reset the properties using Reflexion.
Maybe an issue is that the default value might not be obvious. But you could store the default values for all your bindings in a static object, and copy the value of the property for this reset object into the current status object.
Rq : you could also use reflexion to get the bindings for all control of current GroupBox, and then get the bounded properties from the binding, so no need for a TAG. BUT if a control has several bindings, you won't know which one to reset. In my case, controls within GroupBoxes have also a color binding to indicate wether they have default value (green) or non-default (red), hence the need for a TAG. (BUT the color indicator are read-only so reflexion could, in fact, also be used with a little more use of Reflexion... was just too lazy to change a working logic when i saw that :-) )
I don't know about your bindings so obviously i cannot tell what's best, i hope this thoughs can help.