# Change content in a windows form

Tags: c#

I'm making an application in C# using windows forms, I want to completely swap out all the content in a windows form and replace it with something else. Is there any convenient way to do this?

Example: I have a menu, when I click "start" I want the menu to disappear and the game to start. I'm not using XNA or anything like that which is kind of the point of this whole project.

Comment: see the answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297526/what-is-the-best-way-to-clear-all-controls-on-a-form-c

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953487/remove-hide-tab-headerswitcher-of-c-sharp-tabcontrol/6954785#6954785) which uses a modified tab control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use one `Panel` for each unique content set you want to switch. Hide all of the panels, except the initial one. Create a variable `activePanel`. Set `activePanel` to current shown panel (i.e. initial one).

When you need to switch, do the following:

```
activePanel.Visible = false;
activePanel = <Panel you want to open now>; //I mean the Control, not an ID or something.
activePanel.Visible = true;
```

Another approach is to dynamically remove and add Controls to the form, but this way you'll have to write a lot more code, hovewer, your application memory footprint should be lesser.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me: Adding all the controls like:

```
form.Controls.AddRange(Pages.ToArray());
```

Then activating the needed one with

```
form.Controls[i].BringToFront();
```