# How to change the content of windows form with button control click?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I'm using visual studio 2010 and I have a winforms application.

When I start the application I show the user the 'MainMenu' which have:

1) New Game button

2) Options

each button click create a new form... 
what I want to do when the user clicks on the options button is to change the MainWindow
content to be the Options window content..  and when he accepts the
changes on the options window -> return to the mainMenu view.. is it possible to do?

Comment: See these posts:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297526/what-is-the-best-way-to-clear-all-controls-on-a-form-c

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584902/change-content-in-a-windows-form

Comment: You'll probably need to dynamically create your controls and the layout. Predefine your forms, if necessary. There are some obstacles in creating new forms out of the box, though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either use `Panel`s and switch them round:

```
panelMain.Visible = false;
panelOptions.Visible = true;
```

Or you could have a numerous forms, and show and hide them:

```
frmOptions.Show();
frmMain.Hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

Create multiple Panels and hide and show these on Button click.

```
Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  PanelNewGame.Visible = true;
  PanelOptions.Visible = false;
  PanelMain.Visible = false;
}
```

Depending on the button you click handle them differently

Answer (score 2):

One way you could do it is to use invisible labels and text fields for example, and when the user clicks the Options button then everything becomes clear.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise that you take a look at the  [Tab Control class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx) This control allows you to switch between different blocks of content programmatically using the command

```
tabControl.SelectTab(i)
```

where i is the index of the tab.

Comment: yeah i know, but i don't want to use Tabs

Comment: @Elior you can make a custom usercontrol that behaves like a TabControl without the visuals.. Or your own visuals this does what you want and is wel tested by MS :P

Comment: Fair enough. Are you aware though that you can use the trick detailed in [this stack overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6954785/837194) to hide the actual tab headers, thus giving the flexibility of tabs without the UI ugliness?