# how to use foreach loop for clear the all textboxes?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

```
 public void clear()
  {
    lblage.Text = "";
    lblclosingbirds.Text = "";
    lbltypeoffeed.Text = "";
    lbltypeoffeedf.Text = "";
    lblstdfeed.Text = "";
    lblstdfeedf.Text = "";
    lblstdhd.Text = "";
    lblstdhe.Text = "";
    lblExpeggs.Text = "";
    lblbirdsf.Text = "";
    txtacteggs.Text = "";
    txtactfeed.Text = "";
    txtactfeedf.Text = "";      
    txtfemaleclosingstock50.Text = "";
    txtfemaleclosingstock70.Text = "";
    txtmale50kgcstock.Text = "";
    txtmale70kgscstock.Text = "";
    txtmort.Text = "";
    txtmortf.Text = "";
    txtuseeggs.Text = "";
    ddlFemaleFeedtype.SelectedValue = "0";
    ddlMaleFeedtype.SelectedValue = "0";

}
```

how to use foreach loop method for replace with clear()..please tell me.. any one...
is it possible to write foreach loop...please tell me

Answer (score 6):

```
void ClearAllControlsRecursive(Control container)
{
    foreach(var control As Control in container.Controls)
    {
        if(typeof control is TextBox)
        {
            ((TextBox)control).Text = String.Empty;
        }
        if(control.HasControls())
        {
            ClearAllControlsRecursive(control);  
        }
    }
}
```

then call this method like this:

```
ClearAllControlsRecursive(yourContainer);
```

You can also switch on the control type and clear the values accordingly.

Comment: foreach(var control As Control in (pnl.HasControls()))
{}

Comment: Nope, you need to put the for loop in a method, that takes in parameter a container. Then, you can make it recursive. I edited my Answer with an example.

Comment: Then you should ask another question on this site about it. But before you do that, make sure you actually try to debug and code it. This is not a "do my homework" site.

Comment: Updated the code, Controls is a Property, not a method. Just remove the "()" and it will work ...

Answer (score 2):

```
void ClearAllControlsRecursive(Control container)
{
    foreach (var control in container.Controls)
    {



        if (control is TextBox)
        {
            ((TextBox)control).Text = String.Empty;
        }


    }
}
```

and i cal this method like...

```
ClearAllControlsRecursive(panel1);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

```
foreach (object control in form1.Controls) {
    if (control is TextBox) {
        control.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: i am using .aspx page...so..how it's work..can u please tell me in aspx.cs page...it's not used shekhar

Comment: your code is useful in windows forms application but in aspx page ..it's not work shekhar....so..how to implement in aspx page

Comment: can u say another way please?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this extension method :

```
public static IEnumerable<TControl> GetChildControls(this Control control) where TControl : Control
    {
        var children = (control.Controls != null) ? control.Controls.OfType<TControl>() : Enumerable.Empty<TControl>();
        return children.SelectMany(c => GetChildControls(c)).Concat(children);
    }
```

use :

```
foreach (TextBox tb in this.GetChildControls<TextBox>())
{
    tb.Text = String.Empty;
}
```

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297526/what-is-the-best-way-to-clear-all-controls-on-a-form-c) is a code(answer the question) for clear all controls on the form.

**Another method** :

```
yourForm.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().ForEach(textBox => textBox.Clear());
```